# Image(src drawable) on top of canvas possible?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, paint

I have my RelativeLayout with `ImageView (src="@drawable/logo")`.

Now I used paint in another class to draw 4 rectangles to cover the 4 sides and allow camera preview to appear in the middle.

Can I place my drawable over (on it) a drawn rectangle? I would like to put it as a logo!

Comment: post your code please?

Comment: I have the same problem I am using the code
Canvas cs = new Canvas(bitmap);
 Resources res = getResources();
   Bitmap bitmapx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_good_full);
   Bitmap bitmapxx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_bad_full);
  if(text.equals("Good"))
  {
     cs.drawBitmap(bitmapx, 0, 0, tPaint);
    
    
  }
  else
  {
     cs.drawBitmap(bitmapxx, 0, 0, tPaint);
    
  }